# Is it possible to obtain the algebraic expression of an InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: interpolation

Up until now, I have been trying to obtain an expression for an `InterpolatingFunction` obtained from `NDSolve`, by using the function `Fit` like this:

[image]

```
xTab = Table[{t, var[t]}, {t, 0, 2.0, 0.01}];
xFit = Fit[xTab, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}, x]
```

giving the an expression as the following one:

```
0.359718 - 7.45916 x + 28.9826 x^2 - 38.8259 x^3 + 20.7638 x^4 - 
 3.81347 x^5
```

However, good approximations are dependent on the particular shape of each curve, and in this case, when we plot the original curve (blue) versus de `Fit` version of it (gold), we see the evident error

[image]

I am aware that I could add functions/terms in the `Fit` function like higher order polynomials or even trigonometric functions to improve the interpolation approximation, however the `InterpolatingFunction` at hand is (apparently) already an Hermite interpolating function of order 3:

[image]

How can I extract an expression for this particular `InterpolatingFunction`?

Comment: Assuming `var` was constructed with `Interpolation[data]`, for some data, then it's a piecewise polynomial interpolation of the form in the question linked by @ChrisK. If you got it from `NDSolve`, the form is probably different.  In all cases, it's a piecewise function with degree-3 polynomial pieces, probably a lot of pieces if you got it from `NDSolve`. What do you want to do with the algebraic expression? There may be better alternatives.

Comment: Note that `yFN = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + x y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, 0, 2}]` displays the same information as your `var`, but `Plot[{yFN'''''[x], yFN''''''[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` shows that `yFN` is a piecewise order-5 interpolation, not an order-3 one as its display claims.